# Is a fast valid if the Muslim made the intention to fast on Monday, without knowing whether Monday is tomorrow or such?

Tags: sawm

If someone made the intention (made the intention a few days before Monday, and kept the intention even before Monday's fajr) to fast on Monday, but when Monday came, he didn't know it was Monday until it was almost Dhuhr, and that person had drank after fajr but before he know it was Monday. Should he continue the fast or no?

Comment: Is this a nafl or a Fard fast? The intention that counts as "Niyyah" is at the beginning of a deed not a plan to do something some other day.

Comment: It's a nafl fast

Comment: I see nevertheless there might be different opinions on that.